# how to fix dataSnapshot.getValue() retrieves null?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Okay so I am trying to pull from my database the email of a single user under the userID, and it retrieves null.

The userUID is authUID.

[My Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeHvT.png)

When I change the line to :
String value = dataSnapshot.child("email").getKey();

it retrieves the right key so I am standing on the right position of the database as far as I understand.

```
 myDatabaseRef.child(userUID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try{

                        String value = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                        //String value = dataSnapshot.child("email").getKey(); gets email
                        Log.d("TAG", "onDataChange: " + value);

                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.d("PROBLEM",ex.toString());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

The error that I get:

2019-07-30 10:42:29.566 14673-14673/com.example.h210.housecommitteemanage D/TAG: onDataChange: null

Comment: What the value of  `userUID` in `myDatabaseRef.child(userUID)`?

Comment: what's the database reference you are pointing to when you initialize it ?

Comment: Try this once, `Log.d("TAG", "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.getKey() + ":" + dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, below code will fetch emails of all the users :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DataUsers").child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try{
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                for (DataSnapshot aSnapshotIterable : snapshotIterable) {
                    String value =  aSnapshotIterable.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Users email : " + value);
                }

            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.e("PROBLEM",ex.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```